# how can i generate a SAML Assertation Response with using the metadata?

Tags: metadata, response, x509certificate, saml-2.0

I have som SAML metada but i dont know how to generate a SAML-Response using this metadata for test. do some one knows how to do it ?

````
<md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
hello world
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
hello world
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost:8080/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php"/>
<md:NameIDFormat>
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost:8080/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php"/>
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
```</md:EntityDescriptor>
````

Answer (score 0):

You can see example SAML responses [here](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php).

The `<saml:Issuer>` is your `entityID` from your IdP metadata.

Some service providers (`SP`) require a SAML Response to be signed, in which case you use the private key associated with your `<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">`. The `SP` will have a copy of your metadata and will verify the signature using this block of metadata.

The `<saml:Audience>` is the `entityID` of the `SP`.

Everything else in the response is created from the store of attributes the IdP is using and isn't related to the metadata.